Take screenshot of rendered HTML from Linux without GUI
Is there any smart tool or anything I can use to take a screenshot of a rendered localhost website on a Linux server without monitors?
I am using Rocky Linux 9 and I have done group-install of "Server with GUI" but I did not manage to be able to use XRDP sessions or even create an image of a rendered HTML website from commandline. The server is a cloud server, there is no option to connect a monitor or anything. ;-)
For more details:
I am running a web application on this server, where users can edit things in HTML/PHP. I want to create a rendered version of the current status, that is saved as an image file to share this image in an intranet (which doesn't have direct network access to the web application).

Have a look at Selenium

You can also setting up a VNC session as an alternative to XRDP.

any headless browser will do it.

Google Chrome supports this from command line:
$ google-chrome --headless --screenshot --window-size=1024,4096 https://stackexchange.com/
...
788678 bytes written to file screenshot.png

There is also --print-to-pdf for PDF output.

You can do that with Selenium WebDriver. Here's a StackOverflow thread with some examples in various languages.

I decided to take another way with this.
I am using html2canvas for JavaScript now. There are some fine-tunings to be done, but it works well. Even though, it's a different approach, because it renders the user's view once he clicks a specific button.
Thanks for help!
